# there is a measurable function $f$ on $X$ such that $|{f(x)}|=1$ for a.a $x \in X$ and $\nu(E)=\int_Efd|{\nu}|$ for any $E \in \mathfrak{M}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

any hints on this problem: 
 Let $\nu$ be a finite signed measure on a measure space $(X, \mathfrak{M})$ and let $|{\nu}|$ be its total variation, prove that there is a measurable function $f$ on $X$ such that $|{f(x)}|=1$ for a.a $x \in X$ and $\nu(E)=\int_Efd|{\nu}|$ for any $E \in \mathfrak{M}$

I know that we need to use the Radon-Nikodym theorem, but I don't know how to start!
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\nu \ll |\nu|$.

Comment: hm I never seen this before! so is every finite signed measure absolutely continuous to its total variation?

Comment: Is it possible for $|\nu|(A) = 0$ with $\nu(A)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $|\nu|$, there exists by (Radon-Nikodym) $f\in L^{1}(X,\mathfrak{M},|\nu|)$ such that $d\nu = fd|\nu|$.  Equivalently, $\nu(E) = \int_{E}fd|\nu|$ for all $E\in\mathfrak{M}$.

To verify the other condition, suppose there were an set $U$ of non-zero measure such that $|f(x)|\neq 1$ for all $x\in U$.

Without loss of generality (use measurability of $f$ here), assume that either $|f(x)| > 1$ on $U$ or $|f(x)| < 1$ on $U$.

Then write $U = U_{1}\cup U_{2}$, where $U_{1}$ is a positive set and $U_{2}$ is a negative set.  One of these must have positive $\nu$-measure $0$.

Assume here that $\nu(U_{1})\neq 0$ (the argument should be similar for when $\nu(U_{2}) \neq 0$.

Compute $|\nu|(U_{1})$ by definition and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for the edits, my initial answer introduced issues that weren't necessary and also errantly assumed that $f$ is continuous!

Comment: ok thanx for the help! :)

Comment: no problem!  I made one more edit, sorry!

Comment: You thanked me too soon.  This argument may not work.  I'll think about this more and post back.  My apologies.

Comment: Will work on it and see what I'll get and pots it feel free to correct me.

Comment: OK.  The revised version should work. :)

Comment: I made yet another edit to fix some logic errors.  Sorry I was rushing when I typed this out originally.  If you have trouble filling in any of the details feel free to ask.

Comment: Hank you. But when you say without loss of generality; why do I need to use the measurability of $f$?

Comment: Since $f$ is measurable, so is $|f|$.  Therefore sets of the form $\{x\in [0,1] : |f(x)| > \alpha\}$ are measurable.  Similarly so if we replace $>$ with $\geq, <$, or $\leq$.  So you can intersect these sets with $U$ and the result is still measurable.

If we do not use this, we may have $|f(x)| > 1$ for some values of $x\in U$, but $|f(x)| < 1$ for other values.  This would ruin the argument the follows below.

Comment: Ok got it than you for clarifying

Comment: No problem!  This was helpful for me too. :)

Comment: I noticed you unaccepted this answer.  Is there an error in it that I didn't notice?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not enough to take $A, B \subset X$ such that $\nu^+(E) = \nu(E\cap A)$ and $\nu^-(E) = -\nu(E\cap B)$ and then to define $f(x) = 1$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x) = -1$ if $x \in B$?

We also need that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ (of measure 0 might suffice) and $X = A \cup B$ (less a set of measure 0 might suffice). These are guaranteed by Hahn Decomp.